# transformResponse in typescript to sort a post result

Tags: redux-toolkit, react-typescript, rtk-query

I am trying to sort the response of a post with RTK query but I have this error
"Object is from type unknown"

```
transformResponse: res=>res.sort((a: { id: number; },b: { id: number; })=>b.id-a.id),
```

I am quite newbie with Redux Toolkit and with Typescript: How can I define the type of the result?
Thanks!

I send a post call and I would like to sort my result in desc order, so that I can see in the table of results the new posted article

Answer (score 0):

You have to type the response. Try this:

```
transformResponse: (res: {id:number}[])=>res.sort((a: { id: number; },b: { id: number; })=>b.id-a.id),
```